# Getting pop-up window when cell is selected in flex

Tags: apache-flex

I have a flex datagrid to which I need to add this functionality: user clicks on particular cell, window should pop-up with additional information about the value in that cell.  The pop-up might need to be another datagrid with more info.Can u provide flex code for this.I am new to flex.

Answer (score 2):

```
<!--DGCRenderer.mxml-->
<mx:Label xmlns:mx="http://www.adobe.com/2006/mxml" selectable="true"
  click="handleClick()">
<mx:Script>
  <![CDATA[
    private function handleClick():void
    {
      CustComponent(listdata.owner).showPopUp(this.data);
    }
  ]]>
</mx:Script>

</mx:Label>

<!-- inside the datagrid in the CustComponent -->
<mx:DataGridColumn dataField="name" headerText="Name" itemRenderer="DGCRenderer"/>
<mx:Script>
  <![CDATA[
    public function showPopUp(item:Object):void
    {
      var p:PopUpClassName = PopUpManager.createPopUp(this, PopUpClassName);
      p.setItem(item);
    }
  ]]>
</mx:Script>
```